# Getting IOException when scanning an NFC tag weirdly

Tags: java, android, nfc, ioexception, ndef

When I scan a NFC tag normally, my code works fine. But when I scan it weirdly, by like swiping or something, I can get this error in the console:

```
W/System.err( 8533): java.io.IOException
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.connect(BasicTagTechnology.java:85)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.nfc.tech.Ndef.connect(Ndef.java:71)
W/System.err( 8533):    at myapp.myapp.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:171)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1213)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1225)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2610)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2622)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2631)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:169)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err( 8533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5554)
W/System.err( 8533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 8533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
W/System.err( 8533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

This is my NFC code:

```
ndef.connect();                                                           
NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();                          
if (ndefMessage != null) {                                                
    String message = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
    //Log.w(TAG, "readFromNFC:: "+message);                               
    if (mEvents != null){                                                 
        Log.d(TAG, "mEvents aren't null");                                
        mEvents.success(message);                                         
    }                                                                     
} else {                                                                  
    if (mEvents != null){                                                 
        mEvents.error("ERROR", "empty", null);                            
    }                                                                     
}                                                                         
ndef.close();
```

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: What is your question? [`connect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#connect()) is **documented** to throw `IOException`, so you can't be surprised that it can/does.

Comment: So when a scan of a NFC is done incorrectly it is supposed to throw this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing weird about that behavior.

If "scan it weirdly" means that you scan the tag and pull it out of read range while it is still accessed (e.g. before calling `connect()`), then you should get an `IOException` as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#connect()). You get that IO exception because you try to access an external device (NFC tag) that is no longer available. Hence, communication is no longer possible and the IO operation must be interrupted.

However, when you only want to read the NDEF message from the tag, Android already takes care of this for you before dispatching the tag discovery event to your app. Android passes that NDEF message to your app through the intent extra [EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES). So there is (usually) no need to manually read the NDEF message again (unless the message on the tag changes dynamically).